# Call to undefined function add_options_page()

Tags: wordpress

I developed the plugin for my wordpress project. I successfully tested it on my local xampp server with 5.3 php. Then I uploaded my project to the web hosting with php 5.2. First trouble  which with I faced off was unsupporting anonymous functions in php 5.2. No issue, I redeclared all functions with names. But then I got error Call to undefined function add_options_page(),  which I counldn't explain. Plz help me guys with your advices

My part of code:

```
function mainPage(){
        ///some code
        }

function mainPage2(){

    add_options_page('Submissions of MAIN page contact form', 'Submissions of MAIN page contact form', 'manage_options','ea_submissions2', mainPage());

    }
add_action('admin_menu',mainPage2());
```

I think something wrong with my funcitons, look through it please.
**There is no issue with php 5.2 as I thought, this part of code also doesn't work with php 5.3! Something wrong with my code**

Comment: What version of PHP are you running? What version of WP? If the site is old and on PHP 4, then your WP version is old, and may not support the add_options_page() function.

Comment: wordpress is ok, because as I said it's running well on php 5.3. On the web server with php 5.2 I got this error Call to undefined function add_options_page()

Comment: I meant on your web server, not your localhost.  If your webserver is 5.2, then you should be good.  Does the rest of WP run? Are you sure you got a good upload via FTP - sometimes some files are missing / corrupt during upload.

Comment: @cale_b If you think that my functions are right written so yes, seems to be its upload issue, I try to re-upload at least wp-admin one more time. Thank you!

Comment: @cale_b after wp-admin re-upload the problem is the same

Answer (score 9):

I had a similar problem, turns out I was running a function too early:

Use `admin_init` hook instead of `init`

Hopefully that helps someone out :D

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't work because you have normal function not wrapped in a class, and because add_options_page does not work yet by that time that is why you get the error.

A fix would be to use an anonymous function in the add action call, but hence that does not work on php 5.2.

So long story short, this is fixable though, but you shouldn't run php 5.2 anymore in the first place. PHP 5.5 is already in development and 5.3 is facto standard these days. A solution is to ask your hosting company to upgrade php to at least 5.3 so that you can use anonymous functions and you can hook it to the add action call.

Or, wrap it all in a class and on the admin init function create the new class.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call your code inside admin_menu like this

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', array(&$this, 'addWidgetSettingsMenu' ));
```

Comment: Can you explain what's happening there, specifically `&$this` and `addWidgetSettingsMenu`?

Answer (score 0):

Aware that this is an old question, this is your problem:

```
add_action('admin_menu',mainPage2());
```

Here you are invoking the mainPage2() function and adding the return value of that function as an argument to the add_action method.

You should do

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'mainPage2');
```

This way, the mainPage2 function will be called when admin_menu happens.

Answer (score -1):

Try it without giving space in title :-
SubmissionsOfMainPageContactForm